# Create custom validation callback in form_validation.php using codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, email-validation

Hello i am trying to create a validation callback for my form to validate a field only if it is not empty. I created my validation rules into a config file named **form_validation.php**.
Here is a part of its content :

```
$config=array(
  'Users_Controller/add'=>array(
        array(
            'field'=>'email',
            'label'=>'email',
            'rules'=>'callback_email'
        ),
   )
);

public function email($value){
   if( trim( strlen($value) )!==0 ){
      $this->form_validation->set_rules(
         'email',
         'email',
         'valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
          array(
             'valid_email'=>'invalid email',
             'is_unique' => 'email already registered'
         )
      )
   }
}
```

In my controller,in  **users_Controller.php** here is how i handle the form submission :

```
class Users_Controller  extends CI_Controller{
     public function add(){
         if($this->form_validation->run()){
              $this->User_model->save();
              $this-session->set_flashdata('success','okay');
              redirect('users/list');
         }
         else {
              $this->load->view('add')
         }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, the validation does not take in account the callback validation method i added in the config file **form_validation.php** but if i put this callback in the controller, the validation process ignore all the others rules puted in **form_validation.php**

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link :- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324420/callback-function-in-
codeigniter-with-multiple-parameters-during-form-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this helps you**

**form_validation.php**

```
/*put callback rule in form_validation.php*/

$config=array(
   'Users_Controller/add'=>array(
    array(
        'field'=>'email',
        'label'=>'email',
        'rules'=>'callback_check_email'
    ),
  )
);
```

**put callback method in Users_controller.php**

**In Users_controller.php**

```
function check_email($value)
{
    /*check your email rule here as u want */
    /* this is just example*/ 

    $email= $this->YourModel->getemailofUser();
    if ($value == $email) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_email', 'Your email is not a valid registered email!');
        return FALSE;
    }
```

}

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: thanks i works, but i wanted to keep the callback function in the config file. is there a way to dot that ?

Comment: i never  implement that as no descriptions are given in documentation

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a specific validation rules group, such as `Users_Controller/add`, you need to pass group name to the `run()` method.
**Users_controller.php**

```
    ...
    public function add(){
        if($this->form_validation->run('Users_Controller/add')){
        ...
    }
    ...
```

And for a validation callback to work properly, you have to place the callback method within the same controller of the method that is calling the callback.

Comment: Thanks. i finaly found the solution by adding moving my callback function to the controller.